# JQuery flexslider not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design, flexslider

I have a specific question. If you can go to this website http://mountaingardendiva.businesscatalyst.com/  and help me figure out why the slider is not working, that would be great. I've used the same code for several other websites and for some reason this one is not working. It should be right under the nav bar.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

```js
<!-- Place in the <head>, after the three links -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/jquery.flexslider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>
```

also you have to load your scripts in correct order

Comment: i added those exact lines, per woothemes instructions, but it doesnt work. What do you mean fix my jquery?

Comment: you have to load flexslider.js after jquery.js

Comment: would you mind telling me exactly what that means? I have never had to mess with the code so this is all new to me. Thank you so much

Comment: check your header, you have to load js scripts in right order. Check example above.

Comment: thank  you friend. I had an extra script tag somewhere higher up.